# How to parse and round a string value to the nearest whole number?

Tags: c#, casting, int, string-parsing

I'm passing a string value from a slider control which needs to be in the form of a whole number for processing. Currently if I select a value of 3, the actual string value passed is `3.74`.

I tried to solve this issue by taking the slider value string `roundMax`, converting it to an int and then assinging it's value to the integer flag variable `roundMaxFlag`.

```
int roundMaxFlag = Convert.ToInt64(Math.Round(Convert.ToDouble(roundMax)));
```

This method isn't working as I cannot `implicitly convert type long to int`.

Does anyone know how I can convert the string value from `roundMax` and store it as a whole int in `roundMaxFlag`?

I assume it can be done using the above line of code just that I'm missing an extra cast?

[image: value being passed over in roundMax]

Comment: `Convert.ToInt64` returns `long`, since you defined `roundMaxFlag` as an `int`, there is no implicit conversation between them.

Comment: Typically you'd want to use `double.Parse` or preferably `double.TryParse` to convert a string to a `double`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the method called `Convert.ToInt32`, since you assign your result to an int (Int32) and not to a long int (Int64).

The error message you get, *cannot implicitly convert type long to int.* express the above. For the representation of an int, 32 bits are used. While for the representation of a long int, 64 bits are used. Hence you cannot assign to a variable that expects a 32-bit value, a 64-bit value.

Comment: @BrianJ all we do :). I am glad that I helped.

Answer (score 0):

Try `Math.Ceiling`

It takes a number and rounds it upwards to the nearest integer i.e:

```
string mystr = "7.83"
int roundMaxFlag = convert.ToInt64(mystr);    // converting string to int 64
roundMaxFlag = Math.Ceiling(roundMaxFlag));   // rounding value to next upward integer
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: This isn't going to work. The second line will give the same error that the OP is getting.

Answer (score 0):

Just add `0.5` and convert to `int` using a cast `(int)` and / or truncate, to convert to nearest whole number. (NB: for rounding negative numbers this way, use `-0.5` instead)

Comment: I do not agree. A cast like `(int)` truncates a float, so e.g. 3.74 becomes 3. Adding 0.5 fixes this problem. Example 1: 3.74 --> 4.24 --> 4. Example 2: 3.24 --> 3.74 --> 3.